# Fire an Event if an conditional INSERT or DELETE is preformed in Eloquent model in Laravel 4

Tags: events, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following 3 models in eloquent:

*Business* [id,name]

*MailingList* [id, business_id, name, aggregation]

*Contacts* [id,email,name]

*MailingLists* belongs to one *Business* (hens business_id) and a *Contact* belongs to many *MailingLists*. Now every *Business* has a *MailingList* named "all contacts" in which *aggregation* is set to TRUE.

If a *Contact* is added to a *Mailinglist* of a *Business* it should also be added to the 'all contacts' *MailingList* (but only once). If a *Contact* is removed from the "all contacts" *MailingList* it should also be removed from all the other *MailingList* of that *Business*.

I am sure there must be a way to fire an event if a *INSERT* is preformed on any but the "all contacts" mailinlist and one if an *DELETE* is preformed on the "all contact" mailinglist, only I can't think of one. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `all contacts` is something abstract. It would be wise to redesign it, and instead use it to simply show all the emails from business' lists. This way you won't have to even worry about the thing you are asking for. Anyway you can listen to `creating`/`deleting` events of the `MailingList` (you don't need to fire anything, they are there already http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events) and do the job in the listeners. You should create separate handler class for this - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events

Comment: Hmm that does sound smart now that you mention it. Thank you! if you post it in an answer I can give you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of Eloquent you can use separate models: like `MailingList` and `AggregateMailingList`.

The latter is going to be read-only aggregate of all contacts of given business. You could handle that in the db using view and setting it as `protected $table` property of the `AggregateMailingList`.

This way you won't need to worry about the events you asked for.

---

However, if you like to handle it through the events, check this: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events  and http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events.

I suggest creating separate class as events handler and put your logic there, then simply register it as listener for event eg.: `eloquent.creating: MailingList`